# Show content of tag hovered by draggable div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a movable div (click & drag). I'd like to hover over any text within the HTML, and give an output on console what has been hovered.

As an example, I have a `<p> Text </p>`. If I hover the movable object over that paragraph, console would say.. 'text'

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>text</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you just want to get what it says inside an element? Because, if so, you can have a look at [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Comment: You should take a look at the [elementFromPoint(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) function, you can use it to get the element at the cursor's position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)` to get the element under cursor, and `.textContent` to get its contents as text.

One other thing: you have to set [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the draggable `div` to `"none"` before you call `elementFromPoint`, otherwise the dragged element will be returned.

A complete example:

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";

    elmnt.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    let hoveredElt = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    if (hoveredElt.tagName === "P") {
       console.log(hoveredElt.textContent);
    }
    elmnt.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>text</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```